# How to change the color of substring of Dropdownlist Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I want to change the color of the Dropdownlist item not the full text, but some portion of the text in different color like Listitem text is

> This is **stackoverflow**

In the above suppose stackoverflow will be in Red.

Please Help.

Comment: @Matten: The OP has already tagged it as ASP.NET.

Comment: It's only possible to set a CSS class to the whole ListItem(option in HTML) but not to split the option into multiple spans because only text is allowed in option tags. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION Therefore you can only apply one color per ListItem.

Comment: If you really want to make yourself work hard for little gain - create a button and textbox that ACT like a dropdown list (JQuery would be good here) and on clicking the button you can display a set of <span>s that can contain whatever you want.  FWIW: I don't think its worth the hassle though!

Comment: Thanks all of you . somehow i managed to do it using http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Comment: Well, note that I would DOWNVOTE your solution because you explictily ask about the color of a DropdownList item - which your solution does not use. You replicate the behavior. This is ok - but not n valid answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/ZwmMz/